# Xcode 4 crashes when we run a project at the same time on two machines with Git

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, git, xcode4

We have two developers working on the same project. This project is integrated with Git.

When one developer is working on the project and other developer tries to run the project, Xcode 4 crashes as shown.

[image]

What could be wrong and how to rectify it?

Thanks!

Comment: wow that sounds like a really piss poor bug! No idea how to rectify it though - maybe tell the other guy 'stop working now - I'm compiling'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what has happened is that your project.pbxproj file has gone some merge conflict stuff embedded in it.  Open it in a text editor and look for lines like:

**>>>>>>>**

If you see that, it means you need to clean up the file.

There's no way for git to be doing anything across systems while both developers are just working, so the issue is something someone checked in...

Another issue is that if a project file is changed by another developer, and someone pulls the changes with the project open, they have to re-open the project to see all of the targets as they are meant to be used in the project.  I have not seen that cause a crash though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please let me know where is project.pbxproj file located?

Comment: It's inside the .xcodepro file, which si really a package - right click on that and select "show package contents" to see the files inside.  One of them is a file called project.pbxproj, to edit that you need a plain text editor like text mate or emacs.

Comment: Got the file but there are no >>> characters in it. What should I do now? Please help.

Comment: If there's nothing obviously wrong with the file, you're probably best off creating a whole new project and re-adding the files.